# I just got an error "PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser" [next js]

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I was just going to console log all the id of news in my database. but when I run it and it throw an error like in this picture. How should I fix or solve this?
[image: error]

Comment: This might be helpful too, https://www.prisma.io/nextjs

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to use Prisma on frontend which is not possible. Either use it in next js api routes: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction or use it in getServerSideProps or getStaticProps: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Source: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6219

Comment: API Routes have been replaced by Route Handlers in Next.js 13.2 according to the beta documentation. How can we use Prisma with route handlers?

Comment: @SamHeyman it's exactly the same, Route Handlers are just the name for API routes when using the App directory. they're the same thing